# Coloured Locks on The Escapists

Tags: the-escapists

What do the different colours of locks all mean? There are green ones purple ones and I am really confused what they all mean! There is nothing in the help section or anywhere online, am I just a bit stupid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Green ones unlock doors which are lead to work areas (Laundry Machine place, Gardening Shed etc.)
- Orange (cyan in Mobile/Console) ones unlock those spaces behind the wall, doors in the vents etc.
- Purple ones unlock doors that lead into the facility (I don't think outdoor prisons like San Pancho and Stalag Flucht have purple keys)
- Red ones unlock doors that prisoners can't normally access (Generator room, guard's office)
- Yellow ones unlock your cell door
- White locks lead out of the facility (yes, even San Pancho and Stalag Flucht have them)
- I don't know what blue locks lead to

Comment: blue go's to ladders on console

Answer (score 3):

There are 7 different door lock colours : green, yellow, orange, red, purple, blue, white. The different colours don't show any characteristics about the door (strength, width) except that if you have an orange key it can unlock an orange door and if you have a purple key it can unlock a purple door, etc.

All doors locks obey this rule apart from the blue and white door locks. The white door locks cannot be opened unless in a Prison Takeover scenario. For more info on Prison Takeovers: http://theescapists.gamepedia.com/Prison_Takeover. And the blue doors can simply be passed by wearing a guard outfit.

There are no ways of crafting, receiving, trading, etc. white or blue keys. Each guard holds one of the five different keys (green, yellow, orange, red, purple). If you manage to knock them out, you can steal their key and make a fake key with a wad of putty and return the key to the guard. If the guard wakes up and finds his key missing, you will receive a note from the warden saying 'We have realised a key is missing and we have traced it back to you. As a result of this your penalty is 4 days in solitary.'

Answer (score -1):

They are door locks!They mean that you can only unlock the doors with the same color of keys/key cards. But the white one can only be opened by a prison takeover. You may get keys or key cards dropped by certain guards when you knock them out. Don't be caught attacking the guard or having the key cards though. They are counterfeit items and  you will be confined in solitary for 4 days.

Comment: This doesn't seem to add anything that the current year and a half old answer doesn't already have in it.